# Does the usage of 'ever after' in this line sound weird?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I'm not so proficient in English, but I got this idea for a poem and am trying to write it in English. So I want to write a sentence like:

> *"Nobody saw him ever after."*

But I'm not sure if this is the right way of saying it. Is it?
Also, can you suggest alternative ways of saying this sentence which possibly would sound better in a poem?

Answer (score 1):

"*Ever after*" is a poetic way of saying "*from then on*". It would be perfectly fine to say "nobody saw him from then on", but I'm hesitant to say your example is correct because I've never seen it used with something that *didn't* happen.

It is usually used in a positive sense, that is for things that *did* happen, for example:

- They lived happily ever after.
- That was the name by which he was ever after known.
- She remembered him fondly ever after.

It isn't normally used to describe things that *never will happen*, as in your sentence. For example, it does not sound idiomatic to say "he wasn't known by that name ever after" - we would just say "he wasn't known by that name *anymore*".

"Happily ever after" is something of an exception, because of its perpetual use in fairytales it is has become a phrase in its own right, and people do say "they didn't live happily ever after".

In place of your suggestion I would perhaps say:

- Nobody saw him ever again
- He was never seen again
- He was never heard of again

Comment: That's exactly where my confusion was - whether it can be used in a negative sentence. Thanks for the wonderful answer! "Nobody saw him ever again" certainly sounds perfect here.